# Alterar Texto através de uma classe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, wordpress

Bom dia a todos, estou tentando alterar um texto de um link em um site Wordpress que é o nome de uma categoria, mas quando eu atualizo a página utilizando o código abaixo é exibido rapidamente o texto antigo e depois atualiza para o novo. Não tenho experiência alguma com Javascript, gostaria de saber se tem uma forma de quando atualizar a página já exibir o texto atualizado sem que seja exibido rapidamente o texto antigo.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("li.entry-category a").html("Veja todos os articulistas"); });
```

Comment: O script no Wordpress fica no head?

Comment: Olá amigo, esse script eu inseri utilizando um custom code dentro do template da página, não sei exatamente.

Comment: Tenta apenas colocando `jQuery("li.entry-category a").html("Veja todos os articulistas");`, sem o `jQuery(document).ready(function(){}`... se não funcionar infelizmente é necessário o `ready`, que só é disparado quando os elementos são carregados na página.

Comment: Testei aqui amigo, mas não deu continua com o mesmo comportamento, acho que não vou conseguir fazer essa alteração pois a classe que estou passando no script é utilizada por todas as categorias do site, e está alterando o texto em todo site, tenho o ID da categoria específica que gostaria de mudar mas acho que não seria possível.

Comment: Vc não consegue mudar isso na origem mesmo?

Comment: Por que não altera dentro do admin do WordPress?